# Operation of standard Django view, form and template code to update a model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to understand how a very regularly used code-form in Django views.py actually works. I see the following (or a variation) used a lot, but I can’t find a line-by-line explanation of how the code works  – which I need if I am to use it confidently and modify when needed.
Can you let me know if I have understood how Django processes these various components? If not, please indicate where I have misunderstood.

I will start with the model then introduce urls.py the view and the form. I will go through the relevant parts of the code. I will consider:

The model:

```
#models.py

class CC_Questions(models.Model):
    # defining choices in Model : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/
    personality = [
        ('IF','IF'),
        ('IT','IT'),
        ('EF','EF'),
        ('ET','ET'),
        ]
    q_text = models.CharField('Question text', max_length=200)
    #C1_Type = models.CharField('Choice 1 Type', max_length=2)
    C1_Type = models.CharField(choices=personality, max_length=2)
    Choice1_text = models.CharField('Choice 1 text', max_length=100)
    #C2_Type = models.CharField('Choice 2 Type', max_length=2)
    C2_Type = models.CharField(choices=personality, max_length=2)
    Choice2_text = models.CharField('Choice 2 text', max_length=100)
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.q_text[:20]
```

The url

```
#
#urls.py
app_name = ‘polls’
urlpatterns = [
…..
# ex: /polls/p2create
    path('p2create/', p2_views.p2create, name='p2create'),
…
```

The view:

```
#views.py
from.forms import Anyform
#
def p2create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls/p2')

    else:
        
        form = AnyForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'pollapp2/create.html', context)
#
```

The form:

```
#forms.py
#
….
from django import forms
from .models import  ….. CC_Questions …
…….
class AnyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CC_Questions
        fields = ['q_text', 'Choice1_text', 'Choice2_text','C1_Type','C2_Type']
```

The template:

```
#
# Create.html
#
…..
{% load widget_tweaks %}
…..
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
…
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Choice1_text ">Choice 1</label>
                {% render_field form.Choice1_text class="form-control" %}
                <label for="C1_type">Type 1</label>
                {% render_field form.C1_Type class="form-control" %}
…….
```

Does the code operate as follows?
The user enters URL in browser: http://localhost:8000/polls/p2create/
The urls.py picks the view to execute

```
path('p2create/', p2_views.p2create, name='p2create'),
```

views.py runs the view:

```
def p2create(request):
```

Now, as no form has yet been "identified" or "loaded" (??) the following test fails:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

so the Else clause executes

```
else:
    form = AnyForm()
```

that "sets" the variable ***form*** to "AnyForm()"

The following line creates a dictionary, named ***context***, that creates a key ***'form'*** that is linked with the value ***form*** (=Anyform)

```
context = {'form' : form}
```

The following line searches for create.html in the template directory, passing the directory ***context*** as a parameter

```
return render(request, 'pollapp2/create.html', context)
```

Then template, create.html, displays various input boxes (??) from :

```
<label for="Choice1_text ">Choice 1</label>
{% render_field form.Choice1_text class="form-control" %}
```

When the submit button is pressed on the displayed page, this "passes back" (??) the {% render_field .. %} values to the view (?????)

```
<form method="POST">
...
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
...
</form>
```

the view is executed again (????) , but this time request method is set to "POST" because of the ***form method="POST"*** in the template (?????)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Now the same form , AnyForm , is "reloaded" (????) but with the parameter value "POST"

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AnyForm(request.POST)
```

Now if the form is valid (I have no idea what a "valid" or "invalid" form is)

```
if form.is_valid():
```

then all the values "captured" in the template by (???)

```
<label for="Choice1_text ">Choice 1</label>
{% render_field form.Choice1_text class="form-control" %}
```

(??????)

are written by the view (?????)

```
form.save
```

to the corresponding fields in the ModelForm (?????)

```
class Meta:

    model = CC_Questions
    fields = ['q_text', 'Choice1_text', 'Choice2_text','C1_Type','C2_Type']
```

The view then redirects and loads the home page in the browser

```
return redirect('/polls/p2')
```

Comment: And your question really is ... ?

Comment: @dgw I find your comment unhelpful. I believe it was clear from all the information I provided, as a beginner, I am trying to check how Django processes the various elements in a very frequently used code form. However, I have added further emphasis at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So with the help of the references (mentioned below) and the workflow suggested by you, let us first see, the Django MVT workflow and then address the various questions asked in between the post.

WebForms with Django MVT in brief:

1. Prepare data of several different types for display in a form.
2. Render data as HTML.
3. Edit, enter data using a convenient interface.
4. Validate and clean up the data.
5. Return data to the server.
6. Save, delete or pass on for further processing.

The URL:

When a user requests a page from your Django-powered site, this is the algorithm the system follows to determine which Python code to execute. Which is handled by our views.py. From the frontend, if the request is not 'POST', then it is a GET request, hence the else part of the handling function in the views.py executes. This you have mentioned already.

The View: - Form data sent back to a Django website is processed by a view, generally, the same view which published the form. This allows us to reuse some of the same logic. To handle the form we need to instantiate it in the view for the URL where we want it to be published.

If we use `request.POST`, as in this line:

```
form = AnyForm(request.POST)
```

It transforms the form into a bound form (Form bound with data). Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances).

**Questioned By You (QBY)** - *When the submit button is pressed on the displayed page, this "passes back" (??) the `{% render_field .. %}` values to the view (?????)*

So, yes, If the `action` attribute is not mentioned in the form then the data will be passed to the view responsible for displaying the form.

**QBY** - *the view is executed again (????), but this time request method is set to "POST" because of the form `method="POST"` in the template (?????)*

The button type `submit`, submits the form and make the request a POST request. The Django template sends that submitted data in the `request.POST`.

**QBY** - *Now the same form, AnyForm, is "reloaded" (????) but with the parameter value "POST"*

Here, if the return method at the end of the POST condition is HttpResponseRedirect it will redirect the user to the mentioned URL page, but if the same HTML is used to be rendered then the form will be displayed as a bound form. (It depends upon the requirements)

**QBY** - *Now if the form is valid (I have no idea what a "valid" or "invalid" form is)*

```
Form.is_valid()
```

The primary task of a Form object is to validate data. With a bound Form instance, call the `is_valid()` method to run validation and return a boolean designating whether the data was valid. If yes, then the data is being saved in the model.

**QBY** - *then all the values "captured" in the template by (???)*

All the values are sent to views in the `request.POST`. We can check it by

```
print(request.POST)
```

**QBY** - *are written by the view (?????), `form.save` to the corresponding fields in the ModelForm (?????)*

Save method is called on the Django ModelForm instance in order to save the data to the **database**. Calling save would run the validation check. A ValueError will be raised if the data in the form doesn't validate.

This saved data can now be processed further.

```
References: 
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/][2]
[https://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models_templates.html][3]
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/][4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you have spent reviewing my notes and the specific references I can follow up to improve my understanding.

Comment: Don't wanna be grudging or anything, but wouldn't it make sense to accept the answer that actually helped you in some ways? ;-)

Comment: I definitely intended to do that after reading and understanding your comments. But I recognize the time and effort you put into your reply so I will accept anyway. A fair request, and a fair response.